# Change the default background-color and hover background-color of navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have the following bootstrap navbar: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/xeyanuroya/1/edit?html,output):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdow <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">New</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">Old</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to do the following:

1. change the default background color of the navbar to `#e1e1e1`
2. when we hover on `dropdown` and `help`, the background color of that element becomes even darker (eg, `#a9a9a9`)

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target it with these rules to overwrite the default bootstrap styling.

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover  {
  background: #a9a9a9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <style>
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, 
nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, 
nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
nav.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  background: #a9a9a9;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdow <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">New</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">Old</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to select the elements you wish to change

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #a9a9a9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```css
.nav li {
background: #e1e1e1;
}
.nav li:hover {
background: #a1a1a1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdow <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">New</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">Old</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.fr">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```